# Find $\int_{- 1}^{ 1} xf(x)dx$ if $\ g(t) =\int_{- 1}^{ 1} e^{tx} f(x)dx$, for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let  $f$  be a function from $[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb{R} $ and $g$ from $\mathbb{R} $ to $\mathbb{R} $, both continuous, such that $g(t) =\int_{- 1}^{ 1} e^{tx} f(x)dx$, for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Find $\int_{- 1}^{ 1} xf(x)dx$.

My approach was to observe that, if $x$ takes the value $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$, then $g(\frac{\ln(x)}{x})=\int_{- 1}^{ 1} xf(x)dx$ and by the mean value theorem there is  a $c \in [-1,1]$ such that $$g(t) =\int_{- 1}^{ 1} e^{tx} f(x)dx= f(c)\int_{- 1}^{ 1} e^{tx}dx=f(c)\sinh(t).$$ From this $\int_{- 1}^{ 1} xf(x)dx=f(c)\sinh(\frac{\ln(x)}{x})$, where $\sinh$ is the hyperbolic sinus function (you can find more on Wikipedia). I have a feeling that my solution is not complete. Any help to complete it, please?

Comment: Are you supposed to find the value of the integral in terms of $g$? If so, try differentiating $g$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $x$ is a variable you can't take $t=\ln(x)/x$. On the other hand, note that
$$g'(t)=\int_{- 1}^{ 1} xe^{tx} f(x)dx$$
which implies that $\int_{- 1}^{ 1} x f(x)dx=g'(0)$.

Comment: How did you obtain that formula? And when I apply this to what I said I get that $ g'(t)=f(c)\int_{- 1}^{ 1} e^{tx}dx$ and so I get that $ g'(0)=0$, no?

Comment: @SmC No, $g'(0)$ depends on $f$. If for example $f(x)=x$ then $g'(0)=2/3$.